# How to insert DATE using jsp

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, date, cyrillic

I have a feedback page on my site that contains `name`, `email` and `comments`. Here is my code on `JSP` and I'm using `Apache Tomcat 7.0` and `Oracle DB`

```
String query = "Insert into t_comments(name, email, comments) values('"
                                + realname
                                + "','"
                                + email
                                + "','"
                                + comments+"')";
```

This works great. But I decided to add `DATEC` column (data type `DATE`) to my table `t_comments`. So my query should look like

```
String query = "Insert into t_comments(name, email, comments,datec) values('"
                                + realname
                                + "','"
                                + email
                                + "','"
                                + comments
                                + "',"
                                + "TO_DATE('"
                                + new java.util.Date()
                                + "', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))";
```

And this doesn't work.

```
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

Maybe I insert wrongly type DATE into my table. Also I have another problem. The `name` and `comments` are in Cyrillic. And when they inserted in table, they are displayed incorrect with different encoding. I have this lines in my `JSP` page

```
<%@ page language='java' contentType='text/html; charset=UTF-8' pageEncoding='UTF-8'%>
```

So help me please solve my two problems

1. insert DATE to my table
2. insert Cyrillic words correct to my table

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thank all for your answers. I'm using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to insert `DATE` to my table from @Arvind Sridharan and for cyrillic characters I added the following lines in my jsp

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
realname = new String(realname.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF8");
comments = new String(comments.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF8");
```

Answer (score 1):

Let oracle do it for you instead.

```
String query = "Insert into t_comments(name, email, comments,datec) values('"
                                + realname
                                + "','"
                                + email
                                + "','"
                                + comments
                                + "', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
```

[See this link for more info.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#g1010984)

Comment: it is not exactly what I wanted. Why it doesn't work using java.util.Date()? But for me, there is no matter how to insert DATE, so I will try your offer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should debug your code and check if a Date object toString() matches the pattern expected by Oracle.

Potentially, if you don't want to go in Arvind's way (which I think it's a good idea actually), you can format your Date using [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

You should also consider using a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead of building the statement using String concatenation.